# How to foreach in procedure and return the value under specific condition?

Tags: sql, loops, stored-procedures, recursion, informix

I want to get the highest boss for employee through stored procedure :

Now i have a procedure which bring the direct boss like this :

```
hm_get_my_direct_boss(emp_num).
```

---

If i have an `emp_num = 56`

if i call the procedure `hm_get_my_direct_boss(56)`.
it will return `678` (direct boss).

then if i call it again `hm_get_my_direct_boss(678)` it will return `892`

If i call it third time `hm_get_my_direct_boss(892)` it will return `0`

and that means that `892` is the highest boss for `56`.

i want to do this with `foreach loop in informix` and return the last one before 0 how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter the stored proc `hm_get_my_direct_boss` to the below:

Declare a variable to store the current boss's ID. say Current_Boss_ID

If the direct boss **IS NOT**  0, invoke `hm_get_my_direct_boss(Current_Boss_ID)`.

If the direct boss **IS** 0, `RETURN` the Current_Boss_ID.

`RETURN` lets you return the control flow to the first calling proc.

But a more efficient and cleaner approach to handle these kind of scenarios would be using a [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).